# How handle multiples requests on same resources with $httpBackend

Tags: angularjs

I use `$httpBackend` in a backend-less development :

I have a module called FakeBackend injected in my application :

```
angular.module("FakeBackend", ["ngMockE2E"])
.run(function($httpBackend){
 ...
 ...
function myResponse() {
  return "someting";
}

$httpBackend.whenGET("/api/myRoute").respond(myResponse());


$httpBackend.whenGET(/\/*/).passThrough();
});
```

I do my requests with $http normaly and i get the correct response from the mock. But now I want a dynamic response (for example /api/getTime and the service return a timestamp ) . For now, i only have one same response ( like if it was cached ) for all my requests.
How I can do that? Is it possible?

Comment: can you be more explicit ? and show some code please ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can respond with function and return your need eg .

```
$httpBackend.whenPOST('/api/getTime').respond(function () {
            var timeStamp = new Date().getTime();
            return [200, timeStamp];
        });
```